# Same question with different solution on different OS: new answer or new question?

Tags: discussion

I ran into [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7648200/pip-install-pil-e-tickets-1-no-jpeg-png-support) but on OS X instead of Ubuntu. I figured out the fix on OS X, but the solution is  different because it involves installing appropriate dependencies.

I'd like to document the OS X solution. Should I add a new answer to this question, or open a new question that is specific to OS X?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the question is specific, and/ or the answer will be significantly different, it makes sense to me to make it a separate question.  A reference to the original question can provide scope and let ppl know you weren't making a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

IMO it's not an appropriate answer to the linked question, because the OP isn't using OS X.

It *may* be an appropriate self-answered "new question", although I'm not a huge fan of asking a question just to answer it; that's what a blog is for. OTOH, SO answers turn up high in search results, so it might be the *best* way to disseminate the information. (And you can link to a blog post with additional info :)

Comment: As far as I know, such blog-questions are perfectly fine. At least if they're good questions and good answers, that is.

Comment: @GardenGnobobby Didn't say they weren't--I said I'm not a fan of asking questions just to answer them.

Comment: @DaveNewton Does this mean you are opposed to the new "Answer your own question" feature?

Comment: @LorinHochstein It means exactly what I said: I'm not a fan of asking questions *just* to answer them--IMO that's what blogs are for. I differentiate between that, and asking a question and eventually figuring it out yourself. Would I vote someone down for doing so? Of course not. Am I opposed to the UI feature? I don't care.